# Does it make sense to build a social networking website using Silverlight and Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, silverlight

My web development experience is pretty much non-existent at this point. Therefore, some of the things I'll say may sound pretty stupid. So, consider yourselves warned.

I'm currently looking to build a social networking site and chose Ruby on Rails as a tool to make it happen. However, I'm pretty impressed with Silverlight's capabilities and would love to create a pure Silverlight website. Since Silverlight is a Microsoft technology does it make any sense to combine it with Ruby on Rails? Should I just discard this as a stupid idea and use Microsoft stack for the project with no involvement of Ruby on Rails? If it does make any sense for me to use both Silverlight and Ruby on Rails how would I do this, meaning, how would Silverlight and Ruby on Rails interact?

Now, I know about Silverlight's support of Ruby with IronRuby. However, I'm primarily looking at C# Silverlight. However, if IronRuby is indispensible in this equation, please, bring it up.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Even though it's obvious your very new to this area. Im restraining from answering, without also seeing you take some efforts to accept answers for questions you have already asked. (To do so, click your username above, then pick a question and give it a tick.. rinse.. repeat)

Comment: Sorry about that. I could only get to the last question I posted. I never got around to fixing the problem about which I've posted the question. Therefore, I didn't know if any answers were correct. I was just basically experimenting with stuff. Other than that, if I get a very crucial problem resolved by someone, I'm grateful enough to let that person know, which I've already done with some of my posts on this forum.

Comment: Also, I would like to rephrase the question I've posted here a little bit. I know I can use Ruby on Rails as a back-end. But, does it make any sense to? If I were trying to decide whether to use ASP.NET MVC vs Ruby on Rails as a complete system, I would probably use Ruby on Rails. In this case, since the UI will be rendered completely in Silverlight, are there any obvious advantages to using Ruby on Rails back-end versus Microsoft one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the back-end on Ruby and expose RESTful services.

Then  you could build several clients (Silverlight, Flex, HTML5) that consume the REST Service.

I would NOT start with IRONRuby to build a Silverlight application; it is much easier to find help when using C#.

Comment: I know I can use it as a back-end. But, does it make any sense to? If I were trying to decide whether to use ASP.NET MVC vs Ruby on Rails as a complete system, I would probably use Ruby on Rails. In this case, since the UI will be rendered completely in Silverlight, are there any obvious advantages to using Ruby on Rails back-end versus Microsoft one?

Comment: No. Unless you are able to build on previous knowledge and expertise.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I've been trying to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend going Silverlight + ASP.NET MVC in C#.

Although I have never seen anyone create a Silverlight + RoR site before, I fully believe it would be possible.  So the reason I recommend combining with ASP.NET MVC is because then you won't be effectively switching your entire development stack for doing front-end versus back-end work.  Not just the IDE, but build solution, support community, etc.  Also, if your website ever became popular enough to become a business, just imagine trying to hire a "Silverlight + RoR developer" which is pretty slim odds.